# How to convert .pdf to .png

Tags: java, php

Using ImageMagick I can convert any pdf document into images by using command "convert":

```
convert abc.pdf abc.png
```

This will convert all pdf pages to png images.

How can I implement this using PHP or Java so that I can provide this functionality on my website to enable users to read books online as Google Books does.

Comment: You could consider executing ImageMagick from within Java or PHP if possible

Comment: Apache PDFBox can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189314/convert-a-pdf-file-to-image

Answer (score 4):

There is a Java API for ImageMagick called [`JMagick`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Main_Page).

[Here is a list of available ImageMagick APIs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) for various languages.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Java and the pdf-renderer library. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929813/convert-pdf-to-thumbnail-image-in-java/4930488#4930488) post.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can call Ghostscript from the command line. Ghostscript is freely available.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Programme\\gs\\gs9.00\\bin\\gswin32c.exe", "-dSAFER", "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE", "-sDEVICE=pngalpha", "-r300", "-sOutputFile=C:\\TemplateEditor\\AdGenXTest\\Testdaten\\ActualPNGs\\" + fileName + ".png", "C:\\TemplateEditor\\AdGenXTest\\Testdaten\\ActualPDFs\\" + fileName + ".pdf");

processBuilder.start();
```

Comment: Please respond in english as not all people on SO speak German

Comment: Executing a process from Java is a bit wonky, and there are better in-Java ways to do this -- Apache PDFBox, Aspose, Java SE ImageIO

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good ImageMagick module for PHP. Read all about it at http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [JPedal Java PDF library](http://www.jpedal.org/index.php) can help you?

On they site you can find some demo about converting PDF to image: [PDF to text and PDF to Image Conversion](http://www.jpedal.org/demos_extract.php)