# Convert a PDF file to image

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox, ghost4j

I wanted to convert PDF document into image. I was using Ghost4j.

**Problem:**  Ghost4J needs gsdll32.dll file at runtime, and I do **not** want to use the dll file.

**Question 1:** is there any way, in ghost4j to convert image without the dll?

**Question 2:** I found the solution in PDFBox API. `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPagep 
have method`convertToImage()` which converts PDF page to Image format.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("/document.pdf"));
List<PDPage>pages =  doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = pages.get(0);
BufferedImage image =page.convertToImage();
File outputfile = new File("/image.png");
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
doc.close();
```

I have only text on the PDF document. and I have that Exception when I run this code:

```
Aug 12, 2013 6:00:24 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getawtFont(PDTrueTypeFont.java:481)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.drawString(PDSimpleFont.java:109)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.processTextPosition(PageDrawer.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:496)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:62)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:554)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:125)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:781)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:712)
    at ge.eid.esignature.adessa.pades.sign.PDFtoImage.main(PDFtoImage.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:216)
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.lookupName(TrueTypeFont.java:1153)
    at sun.font.TrueTypeFont.getPostscriptName(TrueTypeFont.java:1205)
    at java.awt.Font.getPSName(Font.java:1156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontManager.loadFonts(FontManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FontManager.<clinit>(FontManager.java:53)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can easily convert [04-Request-Headers.pdf](https://app.box.com/s/gyaysqdwuvkdeckkwdbm) file pages into image format.

Convert all pdf pages into image format in Java using PDF Box.

**Solution for Apache PDFBox 1.8.* version:**

Jar required [pdfbox-1.8.3.jar](https://app.box.com/s/ou532ek91dy9vfp80aa4)

or the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**Here is the solution:**

```
package com.pdf.pdfbox.examples;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ConvertPDFPagesToImages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        String sourceDir = "C:/Documents/04-Request-Headers.pdf"; // Pdf files are read from this folder
        String destinationDir = "C:/Documents/Converted_PdfFiles_to_Image/"; // converted images from pdf document are saved here

        File sourceFile = new File(sourceDir);
        File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir);
        if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
            destinationFile.mkdir();
            System.out.println("Folder Created -> "+ destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if (sourceFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Images copied to Folder: "+ destinationFile.getName());             
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceDir);
            List<PDPage> list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
            System.out.println("Total files to be converted -> "+ list.size());

            String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");             
            int pageNumber = 1;
            for (PDPage page : list) {
                BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage();
                File outputfile = new File(destinationDir + fileName +"_"+ pageNumber +".png");
                System.out.println("Image Created -> "+ outputfile.getName());
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
                pageNumber++;
            }
            document.close();
            System.out.println("Converted Images are saved at -> "+ destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            System.err.println(sourceFile.getName() +" File not exists");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Possible conversions of image into `jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, gif` format.

**Note:** I mentioned the mainly used image formats.

```
ImageIO.write(image , "jpg", new File( destinationDir +fileName+"_"+pageNumber+".jpg" ));
ImageIO.write(image , "jpeg", new File( destinationDir +fileName+"_"+pageNumber+".jpeg" ));
ImageIO.write(image , "png", new File( destinationDir +fileName+"_"+pageNumber+".png" ));
ImageIO.write(image , "bmp", new File( destinationDir +fileName+"_"+pageNumber+".bmp" ));
ImageIO.write(image , "gif", new File( destinationDir +fileName+"_"+pageNumber+".gif" ));
```

**Console Output:**

```
Images copied to Folder: Converted_PdfFiles_to_Image
Total files to be converted -> 13
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:49 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_1.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:50 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_2.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:51 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_3.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:51 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_4.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_5.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_6.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:53 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_7.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:53 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_8.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:54 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_9.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:54 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_10.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:54 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_11.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:55 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_12.png
Aug 06, 2014 1:35:55 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
Image Created -> 04-Request-Headers_13.png
Converted Images are saved at -> C:\Documents\Converted_PdfFiles_to_Image
```

**Solution for Apache PDFBox 2.0.* version:**

Required Jars [pdfbox-2.0.16.jar](https://app.box.com/s/tyxf04ogsc7z2s1qbkxbrosbmtdqdaze), [fontbox-2.0.16.jar](https://app.box.com/s/9pn03f36r8r7kl1svo9hdz4gp5mpgage), [commons-logging-1.2.jar](https://app.box.com/s/mltd3l5t6asdl985ja58sa85bi2ulj5e)

or from the pom.xml dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution for 2.0.16 version:**

```
package com.pdf.pdfbox.examples;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;

/**
 * 
 * @author venkataudaykiranp
 * 
 * @version 2.0.16(Apache PDFBox version support)
 *
 */
public class ConvertPDFPagesToImages {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String sourceDir = "C:\\Users\\venkataudaykiranp\\Downloads\\04-Request-Headers.pdf"; // Pdf files are read from this folder
            String destinationDir = "C:\\Users\\venkataudaykiranp\\Downloads\\Converted_PdfFiles_to_Image/"; // converted images from pdf document are saved here

            File sourceFile = new File(sourceDir);
            File destinationFile = new File(destinationDir);
            if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
                destinationFile.mkdir();
                System.out.println("Folder Created -> "+ destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Images copied to Folder Location: "+ destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());             
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
                PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

                int numberOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
                System.out.println("Total files to be converting -> "+ numberOfPages);

                String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");             
                String fileExtension= "png";
                /*
                 * 600 dpi give good image clarity but size of each image is 2x times of 300 dpi.
                 * Ex:  1. For 300dpi 04-Request-Headers_2.png expected size is 797 KB
                 *      2. For 600dpi 04-Request-Headers_2.png expected size is 2.42 MB
                 */
                int dpi = 300;// use less dpi for to save more space in harddisk. For professional usage you can use more than 300dpi 

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; ++i) {
                    File outPutFile = new File(destinationDir + fileName +"_"+ (i+1) +"."+ fileExtension);
                    BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
                    ImageIO.write(bImage, fileExtension, outPutFile);
                }

                document.close();
                System.out.println("Converted Images are saved at -> "+ destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.err.println(sourceFile.getName() +" File not exists");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error 
May 26, 2015 11:43:31 AM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: BDC
May 26, 2015 11:43:31 AM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EMC
I am using pdfbox 1.8.9 jar

Comment: It's slightly different for the latest version of PDFbox. Use the PDFRendered class.

Comment: pdf that has both text and image content has an issue. I have seen that after the final image(of the input pdf file) is generated the text data gets omitted, only image part (like background image etc) gets displayed. Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Comment: @yeppe provide pdf file as a link. I will provide input to you.

Comment: Perfect, you made this easy for us

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use **NonSequentialParser** to avoid errors with some PDF files (with incremental updates):

```java
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File("/document.pdf"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was helpful for me

Answer (score 4):

The way over PDFBox is a good way to avoid native bindings.
Try to use the PDFImageWriter from the PDFBox, i did the same with it in a few lines and it worked perfectly.
You have to extract the PDFDocument and use the writer with it.

```
PDFImageWriter.write(doc, "png", null, , Integer.MAX_VALUE, "picture");
```

For all pages.

```
PDFImageWriter.write(doc, "png", null, 0, 0, "picture");
```

See:
[PDFImageWriter Javadoc](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFImageWriter.html)

Comment: it have the same exception! :(

Comment: is `PDFImageWriter` more reliably than `ImageIO`? I would prefer using `ImageIO` as it seems simpler... unless it not as reliable

Comment: From my experience, this does NOT write any images from the PDF, can you confirm? I.e. I have an image on my PDF, and it does not show up in the PNG

Comment: where does PDFImageWriter write the resulting image to?

Comment: ImageIO is the one to use with PDFBox 2.0 onwards. Please see the migration guide here:https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have try to convert corrupted PDF file. I've the same errors when the PDF file contains JPXEncoded streams.

Comment: Several PDF parsers now have jbig2 decoders which should be able to handle this

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert PDF into image using **PDFBox**. **renderImageWithDPI** method of **PDFRenderer** class of **PDFBox** is used to convert pdf to image.

```
PDDocument doc=PDDocument.load(new File("filepath/sample.pdf"));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
BufferedImage bffim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNo, 300, ImageType.RGB);
        String fileName = "image-" + page + ".png";
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, fileName, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {           
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(PdfInfo.getPDFWAY());
                if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                    document.decrypt(PdfInfo.getPASSWORD());
                }
                if ("bilevel".equalsIgnoreCase(PdfInfo.getCOLOR())) {
                    PdfInfo.setIMAGETYPE( BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
                } else if ("indexed".equalsIgnoreCase(PdfInfo.getCOLOR())) {
                    PdfInfo.setIMAGETYPE(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
                } else if ("gray".equalsIgnoreCase(PdfInfo.getCOLOR())) {
                    PdfInfo.setIMAGETYPE(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
                } else if ("rgb".equalsIgnoreCase(PdfInfo.getCOLOR())) {
                    PdfInfo.setIMAGETYPE(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                } else if ("rgba".equalsIgnoreCase(PdfInfo.getCOLOR())) {
                    PdfInfo.setIMAGETYPE(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                } else {
                    System.exit(2);
                }
                PDFImageWriter imageWriter = new PDFImageWriter();
                boolean success = imageWriter.writeImage(document, PdfInfo.getIMAGE_FORMAT(),PdfInfo.getPASSWORD(),
                        PdfInfo.getSTART_PAGE(),PdfInfo.getEND_PAGE(),PdfInfo.getOUTPUT_PREFIX(),PdfInfo.getIMAGETYPE(),PdfInfo.getRESOLUTION());
                if (!success) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                document.close();

        } catch (IOException | CryptographyException | InvalidPasswordException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PdfToImae.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
public class PdfInfo {
    private static String PDFWAY;    
    private static String OUTPUT_PREFIX;
    private static String PASSWORD;
    private static int START_PAGE=1;
    private static int END_PAGE=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static String IMAGE_FORMAT="jpg";
    private static String COLOR="rgb";
    private static int RESOLUTION=256;
    private static int IMAGETYPE=24;
    private static String filename;
    private static String filePath="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error:

> org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator INFO: unsupported/disabled operation

You need to include fontbox-1.7.1 jar in the class path apart from Apache pdfbox jar which will fix your issue as PDFBox internally uses fontbox-1.7.1

Comment: The "INFO: unsupported/disabled operation" INFO is harmless and can be ignored. And nobody should use 1.7.1. The current version is 2.0.8.