# How to get a BufferedImage of a File that is not a .jpeg, .gif, .bmp, or .png

Tags: java, image, file, bufferedimage

In Java is there any way to get a BufferedImage of a File that isn't a .jpeg, .gif, .bmp, or .png? More specifically, I would like to be able to create a BufferedImage .jpg. The only way I know of is ImageIO.read, which will return null if the file isn't of any of these types. Is there any other way to make a BufferedImage?
Currently my code looks like this:

```
private void sendImage(BufferedImage image){

    try{
        if(output == null){

            showMessage("MAKE SURE THAT YOU ARE CONNECTED TO SOMEONE!\n");

        }

        else{

            if(image == null)System.out.println("image is null in sendImage");

            output.writeObject("CODE - 4");
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("here");
            output.writeObject(image);
            System.out.println("done");
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("Just sent code " + 4);

        }

    }catch(IOException ioException){

        System.out.println("\nERROR! UNABLE TO SEND IMAGE CODE!");
        ioException.printStackTrace();

    }
```

And the stack trace looks like this:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at server.Server.sendImage(Server.java:432)
    at server.Server.access$300(Server.java:32)
    at server.Server$2.actionPerformed(Server.java:95)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

And yes, the program outputs "here" then crashes with the above stack trace. If there isn't any to get it in a different format, is there an alternative that can be from an image of any format (and for SUPER BONUS POINTS, a serializable one too).

Comment: which format are you working with?

Comment: Preferably I'd at least like to add .pdf and .jpg to that list

Comment: Well PDF is not an image.

Comment: Oh true. Well, do you think that it is better to convert it to a .jpeg or just not give the user the option?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189314/convert-a-pdf-file-to-image).

Comment: Okay. Is there any easier way to do this with .jpg or do I have to do the same.

Comment: Do the same as with `jpeg`.

Comment: Won't that take a while? Also, why is it that it doesn't work on .jpg and is there another class that implements image that can accept .jpg (or .pdf)?

Comment: `ImageIO` works with images, so .jpeg, .jpg, .bmp, .png, .gif should all work the same. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html). PDF is not an image format, so you will have to apply the workaround I suggested earlier. Maybe your .jpg is corrupt or not a valid image?

Comment: Oh I figured out what's happening. So PDFs don't work, but when I tried jpg image the error was arising because BufferedImage isn't serializable. Now I have to get on that problem.

Comment: You create a BufferedImage and use the ImageIO write method to write the image to a file in either jpg, gif, or png format.

Comment: Although PDF is not only an image, it can contain images.

Answer (score 1):

The most common readers/writers of images in Java are:

- javax.imageio, particularly if you add the Twelve Monkeys project jars.
- Java Advanced Imaging, but it seems to have a memory leak sometimes.
- BioFormat, specialized in all the microscopy formats, but also the regular ones.

With both imageio and JAI, you can read/write jpg images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to write your image directly to the stream like that.  What you want is ImageIO.write, like this:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
.
.
.
.
ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);
```

The above code will write your buffered image out as a png.  If you want a jpeg, this should work:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output);
```